# Validação no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou usando um `Form Request Validation` para fazer a validação de um formulário, porém quando deixo um campo do tipo`required` em branco nenhum erro é gerado.

Como faço para gerar um erro quando a validação falhar ?

```
class SaleRequest extends FormRequest
{
   public function authorize()
   {
       return true;
   }
   public function rules()
   {
        return [
            'vendor_id' => 'numeric|required',
            'price'     => 'numeric|required',
            'name'      => 'string|required',
        ];
   }
}
```

Rota:

```
Route::post('/api/list/new/sale', 'SalesController@insert');
```

Controller:

```
public function insert(SaleRequest $request)
{
    $vendorInformation = $this->sale->insert($request->all());

    return response()->json($vendorInformation);
}
```

Model:

```
public function insert($request)
{
     $request['comission'] = $request['price'] * 0.085;
     $sale = $this->create($request);
     return $this->informationVendor($sale->attributes['id']);
}

public function informationVendor($idSale)
{
    return $this->join('vendors', 'vendors.id', '=', 'sales.vendor_id')
                ->where('sales.id', $idSale)
                ->select('vendors.name', 'vendors.email', 
                         'sales.name', 'sales.price', 'sales.comission')
                ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: qual é a versão do teu laravel ?

Comment: 5.4, não tem view, estou retornando um json direto do controller

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: @DavidSantos você manda esses dados via ajax? e quer um retorno se tem problemas com validação?

Comment: eu estou usando o postman para fazer as requisições, queria retornar algum erro caso a validação falhasse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No método do `controller`, não utilize com `FormRequest`, porque, no seu caso não funcionará, então, faça como exemplo abaixo:

Adicione o namespace abaixo que é op  `FACADE` responsável pelo `Validator`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Código alterado:

```
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        [
            'vendor_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'price'     => 'required|numeric',
            'name'      => 'required|string',
        ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return response()
            ->json($validator->errors());
    }
    return response()
        ->json($this->sale->insert($request));
}
```

<sub>Observação: `required` sempre é a primeira validação.</sub>

---

Após essa modificação você terá resposta assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando o model não for satisfatória, e quando tiver tudo correto receberá as informações assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]